# I am trying to get Distinct values when using STRING_AGG within a Case statement. But it is showing all values instead of just 1 each

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

If the requirement is mandatory, then I need a * in front, and if it isn't mandatory, then no * in front. I added the following into the unions of the view, and it pulls the data, but if the movement has more than one stop with the same requirement(s) it list them all, and I only need single values.
This is the script that I inserted

```sql
Select Top 1 STRING_AGG (iif( lrq_manditory = 'Y' ,CONCAT ('*',lrq_equip_type,' ',lrq_type),CONCAT(lrq_equip_type,' ',lrq_type)),', ')
WITHIN GROUP (Order by lrq_equip_type,lrq_type)
from loadrequirement Where mov_number = oh.mov_number
```

and this is the results

```
DRV FST, *DRV UVAX, DRV FST, *DRV UVAX, DRV FST, *DRV UVAX, DRV FST, *DRV UVAX
```

Where you have 4 stops that each require a UVAX and FST, but if there are duplicate requirements, I only need to see one.

Comment: Sample data and expected data will help us help you here. Also, why are you using `TOP (1)` here?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Not sure what you mean about Sample data, the results that I get are in the question, and the expected results would be just DRV FST, *DRV UVAX as the return rather than 4 duplicates of the same values. I had Top 1 in there trying to get just a single result

Comment: I am not sure how to explain what I am trying to achieve here. I can't put the entire view in, it is too large, and when I try and explain that this is for transportation orders and resource requirements, I also run into character limits. I will keep searching on line and go elsewhere. Just trying to get the results from duplicating

Comment: your question is not clear, we don't know your business model and terminology. Perhaps provide a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also look at [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). It looks at a guess that you need to de-dupe *before* aggregating.

Comment: I don't know how I can create a minimal example. there are too many tables that feed this view, and there are not enough characters allowed to afford me the ability to get the point across. Bottom line is customer calls in an order, there may be 4 stops, 1 pickup and 3 deliveries, each delivery may have the same requirement that the driver has to have a FAST certification, I was trying to pull the requirement(s) DISTINCT, into the view so a dispatcher can see it and pick a driver that meets that requirement. I was trying to pull distinct instead of 3 of the same requirement.

Comment: Sample data: Examples of what your data looks like *before* your attempt(s) are applied.

Comment: @MDaniel If you can't create an MRE, then you can't robustly test or validate your solution. I strongly recommend you read the links and take this as an opportunity to learn how to write MREs and Tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
DECLARE @data table ( lrq_manditory varchar(1), lrq_equip_type varchar(50), lrq_type varchar(50) );
INSERT INTO @data ( lrq_manditory, lrq_equip_type, lrq_type ) VALUES 
    ( 'N', 'DRV', 'FST' ), ( 'Y', 'DRV', 'UVAX' ), ( 'N', 'DRV', 'FST' ), ( 'Y', 'DRV', 'UVAX' ), ( 'N', 'DRV', 'FST' ), ( 'Y', 'DRV', 'UVAX' ), ( 'N', 'DRV', 'FST' ), ( 'Y', 'DRV', 'UVAX' );

SELECT STRING_AGG ( list, ',' ) AS list_types FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            CONCAT ( CASE lrq_manditory WHEN 'Y' THEN '*' ELSE '' END, lrq_equip_type, SPACE(1), lrq_type ) AS list
    FROM @data
) AS x;
```

**RETURNS**

```
+-------------------+
|    list_types     |
+-------------------+
| *DRV UVAX,DRV FST |
+-------------------+
```

So perhaps something like:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG ( list, ',' ) AS list_types FROM (

    SELECT DISTINCT
        CONCAT ( CASE lrq_manditory WHEN 'Y' THEN '*' ELSE '' END, lrq_equip_type, SPACE(1), lrq_type ) AS list
    FROM loadrequirement WHERE mov_number = oh.mov_number

) AS x;
```

This is an example as I do not know your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual example for you.

It follows the same **minimal reproducible example** paradigm for answers too. You copy it as-is to SSMS, execute it, and it is working.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, state CHAR(2), city VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (state, city) VALUES
('FL', 'Miami'),
('FL', 'Orlando'),
('FL', 'Miami'),
('TX', 'Dallas'),
('TX', 'Austin');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- duplicate cities
SELECT state 
    , STRING_AGG(city, ', ') AS cityList
FROM @tbl AS t
GROUP BY t.state;

-- first, filter out duplicate cities 
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT state, city 
    FROM @tbl
    GROUP BY state, city
)
SELECT state 
    , STRING_AGG(city, ', ') AS cityList
FROM rs AS t
GROUP BY t.state;;
```

**Output**

| state | cityList |
| --- | --- |
| FL | Miami, Orlando |
| TX | Austin, Dallas |